# Exclude column from export in Datatables Buttons

Tags: php, jquery, datatables, datatable-buttons

I have the following initialization for my datatables:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.datatable').dataTable({
       dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
                    {
                        extend: 'copyHtml5',
                        text: 'Copy Content to Clipboard',
                        className: 'btn',
                    },
                    {
                        extend: 'excelHtml5',
                        text: 'XLS Download',
                        className: 'btn',
                        "mColumns": [ 8 ]
                    },
                    {
                        extend: 'csvHtml5',
                        text: 'CSV Download',
                        className: 'btn',
                        "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
                             console.log(data);
                        }

                    },
        ],

    });
});
```

I am using Datatable Buttons as tabletools is deprecated from data table and tried many options:

```
"mRender": function (data, type, row) {
                                 console.log(data);
                            }
```

Also tried:

```
"mColumns": [ 8 ]
```

I have tried applying the different parameters in various ways but there is something missing in my understanding.Kindly help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Look for [**`exportOptions.columns`**](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/print/columns.html), `exportOptions` let you define a [**column-selector**](https://datatables.net/reference/type/column-selector) the same way as you would target specific columns for filtering and so on. Example, include only the third and fourth column in a PDF export :

```js
$('#example').DataTable( {
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  buttons: [
    {
      extend: 'pdf',
      exportOptions: {
        columns: [ 2, 3 ]
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

demo -> **https://jsfiddle.net/r9Lqbhz4/**

Other examples :

```js
exportOptions: {
   columns: ':visible' //visible rows
}
exportOptions: {
   columns: ['.export', '.important'] //by class selector
}
```

And so on, see the above mentioned [column-selector](https://datatables.net/reference/type/column-selector) page,

*As per comment*: All visible columns except for one in particular :

```js
exportOptions: {
   columns: ':visible:not(:eq(2))' 
}
```

Will include all visible columns except column #2, the third column. Be aware that the `eq()` column index is based on visible column indexes.

Comment: is there a "not" option for showing all visible columns except for one in particular?

Comment: @pbarney, That was a good one! Have updated the answer.  You can use jQuery `:not` and `:eq` selectors to do that.